# Radio field not included in FormData.entries()

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-data, bulma

I am looping through `FormData.entries()` when performing form validation.  However the entries do not include a radio button.  The following is how I initialize my loop, and I have added the logging:

```
for (let [fieldName, val] of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(fieldName);
```

This results in the following being emitted to console:

- name
- email
- property
- deliveryAddr
- startDate
- duration
- other

I expected `deliveryCity` to come right after `deliveryAddr`.  Below is the block of code that contains them both.  Please note various classes are from Bulma.  My first thought was that I had not specified the `value` attribute for the radio buttons, but adding those did not result in `deliveryCity` being added to the `FormData.entries()`  Thanks for having a look.

```html
<div class="mt-2 is-hidden abc-contact-form-delivery-required-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery Street Address</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right abc-featured-property-label">
      <input class="input" type="text" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-addr" name="deliveryAddr" placeholder="Your Beach Home Address">
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-road"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery City</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="mb-3 abc-featured-property-label">Sorry we do not deliver to Fort Morgan</div>
    <div class="field abc-featured-property-label">
      <div class="control">
        <label class="radio is-size-5">
          <input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Orange Beach" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city">
          Orange Beach
        </label>
        <label class="radio is-size-5">
          <input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Gulf Shores" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city">
          Gulf Shores
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that's how the `FormData` constructor behaves. When you have your radios not selected that basically means their value is `undefined`. In JS lingo `undefined` kinda means *no defined property*. So the `FormData` skips inputs with undefined values. When you select the radio input it becomes available in the `formData`.
As you can see the default value of an empty text box is an empty string `""` so it's not `undefined` and the text box is added to the `formData`. Anyway I don't recommend to have not pre-filled radio buttons in a form. Not good for UX. Provide some `undefined` selected radio input at least. Or use a select box as an alternative.

```js
let counter = 0;

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  
  const formData = new FormData(e.target, e.target.querySelector('button'));
  
  for (let [fieldName, val] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(counter, ':', fieldName, JSON.stringify(val));
  }

});
```

```html
<form>
<div class="mt-2 is-hidden abc-contact-form-delivery-required-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery Street Address</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right abc-featured-property-label">
      <input class="input" type="text" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-addr" name="deliveryAddr" placeholder="Your Beach Home Address">
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-road"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery City</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="mb-3 abc-featured-property-label">Sorry we do not deliver to Fort Morgan</div>
    <div class="field abc-featured-property-label">
      <div class="control">
        <label class="radio is-size-5">
          <input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Orange Beach" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city">
          Orange Beach
        </label>
        <label class="radio is-size-5">
          <input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Gulf Shores" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city">
          Gulf Shores
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are validating the form I think that you should stick to the defaults as much as possible.

- Set the `required` attribute in input elements
- Use the build in event listeners

So, here is an example. Read the comments to see what the different event listeners do.

```js
const beaches = ['Orange Beach', 'Gulf Shores', 'Perdido Key', 'Fort McRee', 'Langdon Beach', 'Pensacola Beach', 'Pensacola Dog Beach', 'Opal Beach', 'Navarre Beach'];

// Specific input to the deliveryAddr input
document.forms.form01.deliveryAddr.addEventListener('input', e => {
  // fetch array of beaches if needed
  
  // if beach is in the array set the pattern
  // to be the current value and thereby the input to be valid.
  if (beaches.find(beach => beach == e.target.value)) {
    e.target.setAttribute('pattern', e.target.value);
  }
});

// Any input to any input in the form
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  // if some input, test if input is valid and if so
  // remove the class 'invalid' being there or not on the div.control
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.closest('div.control').classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});

// If submit button if clicked or the function checkValidity()
// on the form is called this eventlistener will trigger.
// This overrides the default message by calling e.preventDefault();
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // when something is invalid (input element being e.target)
  // set the div.control to be invalid
  e.target.closest('div.control').classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

// If form is valide and the form is submitting
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('form submitting...');
}, false);
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: thin solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: thin solid green;
}

div.control span {
  display: none;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.control.invalid span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <div class="mt-2 is-hidden abc-contact-form-delivery-required-fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery Street Address</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
      <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right abc-featured-property-label">
        <input class="input" type="text" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-addr" name="deliveryAddr" placeholder="Your Beach Home Address" pattern="abc" required>
        <span>Beach not valid</span>
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fas fa-road"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="label is-size-4">
      <span class="mr-1 has-text-primary-dark">Delivery City</span>
      <span class="has-text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
      <div class="mb-3 abc-featured-property-label">Sorry we do not deliver to Fort Morgan</div>
      <div class="field abc-featured-property-label">
        <div class="control">  
          <label class="radio is-size-5"><input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Orange Beach" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city" required>Orange Beach</label>
          <label class="radio is-size-5"><input type="radio" name="delivery-city" value="Gulf Shores" class="abc-contact-form-field-delivery-city">Gulf Shores</label>
          <span>Beach not selected</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```